# Changing the Date Format in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working in a ListView in Django where i would like to show the objects from a database that contain the current date, and i was trying to do this using a queryset and the datetime module, but the terminal throws the following error:

## Error

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'05/19/20D/00M/2020YYY' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

## Views

```
class AppointmentIndexView(ListView):
    model = Consults
    template_name = 'appointments_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'consults'
    paginate_by = 7

    queryset = Consults.objects.filter(Fecha=date.strftime("%DD/%MM/%YYYY"))
```

## Model

class Consults(models.Model):

```
#General Consult Info
Paciente = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Paciente')
Fecha = models.DateField()
Motivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
Padecimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
#Main Patient Info
Presion = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
Temperatura = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
Peso = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
Talla = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
#Any Exams done before
Estudios = models.ImageField(upload_to='studies',blank=True)
#Interrogatory by System
Digestivo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Endocrino = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Renal = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Linfativo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Respiratorio = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
#Physical Exploration
Cabeza = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Torax = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
#Diagnose
CIE_10 = models.ForeignKey(CIE_10,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True,null=True)
Detalle_de_Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Procedimiento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Analisis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
#Treatment
Medicamento = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Uso = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Dosis = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
Acciones = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
```

I don't know if i am doing wrong in the use of the datetime module, the view or is there any django settings i should change, if that is the case, how do i do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:
`queryset = Consults.objects.filter(Fecha=date.strftime("%DD/%MM/%YYYY"))`
with 
`queryset = Consults.objects.filter(Fecha=date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))`
If you use `%` sign, you don't need to repeat the character after it. To get available formats, look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'19/05/20' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Comment: queryset = Consults.objects.filter(Fecha=date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

Comment: updated my answer, just use the correct order as mentioned in document I've linked.